# On UNO, when serial.print to UART pin 11, nothing comes out of pin 11

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

The problem: Message prints only to the Arduino IDE's **Tools > Serial Monitor**, not coming out of TX pin 11. 
Question, please how to get Arduino Uno or Mega to send data out of pin 11?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13); // RX, TX pins on Arduino
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.print("This is a test\n\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Where in that code are you doing anything at all with pin 11?!

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's only coming out on the serial monitor - you are printing it to the hardware UART which comes out on the serial monitor.

You have created a SoftwareSerial object which you are then completely ignoring and then using the HardwareSerial UART object instead, which is on pins 0/1.

If you want to use a SoftwareSerial object you should actually *use* the SoftwareSerial object.

Replace all the references to `Serial` with `mySerial` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer.  I will try that immediately.

Comment: I change  to my Serial and had to add mySerial.begin(9600).   Now it works. Thank you Majenko.